.NET MAUI Android File Provider Path
Currently I am updating my Xamarin project to MAUI.
Now I have trouble with the Android File Provider Path File.
In the Manifest.xml I set
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@values/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>

Under "Platforms/Android/Resources/values" I created a file called "file_paths.xml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
 <external-files-path name="my_images" path="/images" /> 
</paths>  

Build-Action - AndroidResource
When I build the project I get this error:
Resources/values/file_paths.xml(2): error APT2230: root element must be <resources>.
VisualStudio for Mac 17.6.14
.NET8

Firstly, change your android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" to android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" . Then, change the value of path to    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />

I worked this one out.
The file_paths.xml file must go inside an Resources/xml folder, not Resources/values.
e.g. App/Platforms/Android/Resources/xml/file_paths.xml
And make sure your File Provider is configured to reflect that.
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>

Seems the compiler expects files in the values folder to be formatted in a specific way.

Why the downvote? This is quite literally the issue in the original post. The path being used is values/file_paths which, if the file is in that directory, will result in the OPs error. The file must be put in ../Resources/xml/ folder and provider set to @xml/file_paths for this error to be resolved.

Not my downvote =( But, yeah. this works. figured it out myself some days before, but forget to answer my self =/

As the error message said: root element must be <resources> 
Make sure you have your resource file with a <resources> tag as root element.
Please refer to this sample resource file from MAUI project template:
App/Platforms/Android/Resources/values/colors.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#512BD4</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#2B0B98</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#2B0B98</color>
</resources>


when wrapping it with a , I got error "APT2000: unknown resource type 'paths'". Removing the "paths"-tag "error APT2000: unknown resource type 'external-files-path'".

@chresben check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/79094906/8297031
